# Underscore symbol ("_") becomes undefined in nodeJS command line interface

Tags: node.js, scope, underscore.js, undefined, command-line-interface

```
$ node
> _=1
1
> _
1
> _
1
> 
undefined
```

That is, the `_` variable seems to become undefined after a single command which doesn't reference it. By comparison:

```
> ubuntu@tm-dev /usr/share/tilemill $ node
> a=1
1
> 
undefined
> a
1
>
```

Is this normal? Why does it do this?

(It's making it a bit hard to debug some code using the Underscore library.)

Comment: OIC. That's the (intended) behaviour of _ in the CLI - it takes the last return value. http://nodejs.org/api/repl.html#repl_repl_features

Comment: Glad to see you found your answer. 
By the way, I wouldn't use node to debug my code, not when you can use https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector

Comment: Thanks for the reminder - I have used that in the past. This was just for trying to understand the behaviour of some very localised string munging.